# How to iterate over a list of maps with indexes using java stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to iterate over a list of maps in java, but I can not figure it out how. I need to keep the index as well.

for example, I have a list of maps like

```
List<Map<String, String>> ListOfMaps = new ArrayList<>();
```

and the output that I want is something like:

```
"ListOfMaps[index].map(k) => ListOfMaps[index].map(k).getValue()"
```

I appreciate if you can give me some hint how I can do it using java stream operators, with high performance.

Comment: Also check out https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-indices

Comment: [Program to Iterate over a Stream with Indices in Java 8](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-iterate-over-a-stream-with-indices-in-java-8/)

Comment: I find this question very unclear. Can you please provide an example input and the expected output for that input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an advocate for streams, I personally don't like using them here. But I will anyhow:

```
IntStream.range(0, mapList.size())
    .forEach(index -> {
        Map<String, String> map = mapList.get(index);
        System.out.println("ListOfMaps[" + index + "]" ...);
    })
```